# Python - Substituting regex matches in byte file

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

Struggling to automate a text file cleanup for some subsequent data analysis. I have a text to tab file where I need to remove instances of \t" text (remove the " but keep the tab).

I then want to remove instances of \n where the character *before* is nor \r. i.e. \r\n is OK x\n is not. I have the first part working but not the second part any help appreciated. I appreciate there are probably way better ways to do this given I'm writing then opening in a byte format simply because I can't seem to detect /r in 'r' mode.

```
import re
import sys
import time

originalFile = '14-09 - Copy.txt'
amendedFile = '14-09 - amended.txt'

with open(originalFile, 'r') as content_file:
    content = content_file.read()

content = content.replace('\t\"','\t')

with open(amendedFile,'w') as f:
    f.write(content)

with open(amendedFile, 'rb') as content_file:
    content = content_file.read()
content = re.sub(b"(?<!\r)\n","", content)

with open(amendedFile,'wb') as f:
    f.write(content)

print("Done")
```

For clarity or completion, the python 2 code below identifies the positions that I'm interested in (I'm just looking to automate their removal now). i.e.

\r\nText should equal \r\nText

\t\nText should equal \tText

Text\nText should equal TextText

```
import re
import sys
import time
with open('14-09 - Copy.txt', 'rb') as content_file:
    content = content_file.read()

newLinePos = [m.start() for m in re.finditer('\n', content)]

for line in newLinePos:
    if (content[line-1]) != '\r':
        print (repr(content[line-20:line]))
```

Thanks as always!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use `([^\r])\n` as your pattern, and then substitute `\1` to keep the character before.

So your line would be

```
content = re.sub(b"([^\r])\n",r"\1", content)
```

Comment: This is really close but I'm looking to remove the char. I can see it in notepad++ as CRLF - equiv to /r/n (as opposed to the original CR /r). I'm guessing when I write out via 'w' that it changes CR to CRLF so switched the code around although I exhibit same behaviour. Any ideas? ie detect /r not proceed by /n and *remove* the /r?

Comment: Thanks - ignore last comment. This works perfectly provided I execute the write rb first as otherwise it automatically appends \n as \r\n! I was executing one of the opens in the wrong order.